# php associative array class variables

Tags: php, oop, class, object

so I have this class

```
class A{

  public $something['aaa'] = 'soemthing';

}
```

but then it complains that there is syntax error....

how can I set class variables in PHP as an associative array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I'm right saying this.. but you might have to declare it in the constructor:

```
class A{

  public $something; // or $something = array();

  function __construct($something){
     $this->something['aaa'] = $something;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's strange.  I don't think that's invalid syntax but it is throwing an error on my end. Maybe the parsre just isn't equipped to handle an property being initialized in that way.  When I tried the following equivalent initialization it seemed to work just fine:

```
<?php
class A {
  public $something = array("aaa" => "something");
}
?>
```

Comment: The syntax in the opening post is not invalid per se, but it´s incomplete. It´s assigning the value 'soemthing' to the key 'aaa' in the array $something... but nowhere it´s $something declared as an array. In your code, you are expliclty declaring $something as an array, and also asigning that key => value  at the same time, but the important part is the declaration.